# How do i setup magnific-popup

Tags: magnific-popup

I am Really new to this so please keep that in mind before judging me.

I am having problems getting the script to work for me.

What i did was following:

1. I built my js with the builder on the Page [Magnific - Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/#mfp-build-tool)
2. I downloaded the CSS File.
3. I included the scriptfile just before the /body tag
4. I tried to open popup with:
   `<a class="popup-iframe mfp-iframe" href="index.php/9-uncategorised/230-contact">contact</a>`

I dont know what i am missing here :( i tried different classes, dont know which they were.

Any help would be really appreciated

**EDIT:** nvm i fixed it for me with downloading a other plugin (NoNumbers Modals) Now everything works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it for me with downloading a other plugin (NoNumbers Modals) Now everything works for me.